# Need help for AdWhire(admob) about "Unable to fill ad request. This is a common situation"

Tags: iphone, admob, adwhirl

**Hello Guys,
Now I am doing the adwhirl development. When downloaded the latest AdWhirl and AdMob SDK. Read and done with the instructions in the AdWhirlSDKInstructionsforiPhone.pdf, I receive below error message.**

2010-10-25 23:52:20.774 iAdWhirle[2017:207] Unable to fill ad request.  This is a common situation.

2010-10-25 23:52:20.825 iAdWhirle[2017:207] Failed to receive ad from admob, will use backup. Error: no error

2010-10-25 23:52:24.881 iAdWhirle[2017:207] Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn's be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x7d13ff0 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}

2010-10-25 23:53:21.550 iAdWhirle[2017:207] Unable to fill ad request.  This is a common situation.

2010-10-25 23:53:21.550 iAdWhirle[2017:207] Failed to receive ad from admob, will NOT use backup. Error: No more ad networks to roll over

**Kindly please give me some suggestion. Thank you.**

---

Thanks for your reply. I am now running adWhirl official demo program, replace the original SDK Key with my Key, then can get the advertisement with high fill rate. But I do not know why when I merge it into my app, the fill rate decreased so much, almost zero.

Br,

Answer (score 2):

I use AdWhirl too, and it seems to work.

"Unable to fill ad request. This is a common situation." just means there is currently no ad available for showing. Thats not a problem.

"Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn's be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content"

This is a common problem too, AdWhirl doesn't implement one of the iAd delegate methods.
You don't have to care about either error.

I haven't seen the third one yet, but it just seems to suggest, that there are no more Ad Networks to try to ask for an Ad. Mayve set up a personal ad on the AdWhirl Webformular, to fill the idle times :)

Comment: what do u mean AdWhirl doesn't implement one of the iAd delegate methods? why?

Comment: in 2010 the AdWhirl-class didn't respond to an iAD delegate call. Since you should currently use Admob Mediation and adwhirl is outdated, this ceased to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the error: 
2010-10-25 23:53:21.550 iAdWhirle[2017:207] Failed to receive ad from admob, will NOT use backup. Error: No more ad networks to roll over

Are you using only Admob? Backup will be used if you have multiple ad networks configured on AdWhirl server.